# Poor practice to push Snowflake account, database, warehouse names to version control?

Tags: security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it a security issue to push the SF account, database, and warehouse names to VC? There are no user/passwords pushed. I don't know enough to determine if these need to be purged or if it's not worth the trouble because these are non-sensitive. Seems like it the account name makes up part of the SF compute URL: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008kp4rJSAQ/how-do-i-find-mt-account-name-please

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I can’t see why this would be a security issue. If someone can log into your VC, extract this information and then log into your Snowflake account then you have bigger security issues than this information being in your VC

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we should not push those information in the version control. Even if you are not exposing your user and password, someone can still try to do a brute force attack. These informations are best stored in the respective cloud providers secret manager service. For example, if snowflake in on AWS, you will use AWS Secrets Manager. During run time, the program will fetch the values from the secrets manager, construct the connection URL and then return the connection object for further processing.